# Retornar uma lista de lista contendo números pares em uma lista e números impares em outra lista?

Tags: java

Boa noite!! Preciso criar um método que receba uma lista de números inteiros e retorne uma lista dessa lista, contendo em uma das listas os números pares e em outra lista o números
impares. Até no momento consegui fazer só isso:

```
    public List<Integer> listaparesimpares(List<Integer> numeros){
    List<Integer> listaparesimpares = new ArrayList<>();

    listaparesimpares.add(1);
    listaparesimpares.add(2);
    listaparesimpares.add(3);
    Integer par = 0;
    Integer impar = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < listaparesimpares i++)
        if(i % 2 ==0) {
            List<>
        }




    return listaparesimpares;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução seria retornar uma Lista de uma lista de de inteiros que teria na primeira posição os numeros pares e na segunda os impares, ficaria assim:

```
public List<List<Integer>> listaParesImpares(List<Integer> numeros) {

    // Instancia uma lista para numeros pares e uma para os impares
    List<Integer> listaPares = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> listaImpares = new ArrayList<>();

    // Para cadas numero na lista de numeros passados no parametro faça
    numeros.forEach(numero -> {
        // Se o numero for divisivel por 2 adicione-o a lista de pares
        if (numero % 2 == 0) listaPares.add(numero);
        // Senao adicione-o a lista de impares
        else listaImpares.add(numero);
    });

    // Criasse uma Lista de Listas de inteiro
    List<List<Integer>> resultado = new ArrayList<>();

    // Adicionasse a lista de numeros pares
    resultado.add(listaPares);

    // Adicionasse a lista de numeros impares
    resultado.add(listaImpares);

    // O resultado sera uma lista onde no indice 0 voce
    // tera uma lista contendo os numeros pares e no indice 1
    // uma lista dos numeros impares
    return resultado;
}
```

Você poderia usar essa função da seguinte forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<List<Integer>> listaParesImpares = listaParesImpares(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));

    System.out.println("Impressao dos Numeros Pares");
    List<Integer> listaPares = listaParesImpares.get(0);
    listaPares.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("\n\n");

    System.out.println("Impressao dos Numeros Impares");
    List<Integer> listaImpares = listaParesImpares.get(1);
    listaImpares.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Uma outra solução porém que eu considero melhor seria retornar um Map de String e Lista de inteiros, nessa solução o map teria uma entrada "pares" que conteria a lista de números pares e uma entrada "impares" com a lista de números impares, ficaria assim:

```
public Map<String, List<Integer>> mapParesImpares(List<Integer> numeros) {

    // Instancia uma lista para numeros pares e uma para os impares
    List<Integer> listaPares = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> listaImpares = new ArrayList<>();

    // Para cadas numero na lista de numeros passados no parametro faça
    numeros.forEach(numero -> {
        // Se o numero for divisivel por 2 adicione-o a lista de pares
        if (numero % 2 == 0) listaPares.add(numero);
        // Senao adicione-o a lista de impares
        else listaImpares.add(numero);
    });

    // Criasse o Map
    Map<String, List<Integer>> resultado = new HashMap<>();

    // Adicionasse a lista de numeros pares
    resultado.put("pares", listaPares);

    // Adicionasse a lista de numeros impares
    resultado.put("impares", listaImpares);

    // O resultado sera uma map onde para a chave "pares"
    // tera uma lista contendo os numeros pares e para a chave "impares"
    // uma lista dos numeros impares
    return resultado;
}
```

Para usar essa função seria:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<Integer>> mapParesImpares = mapParesImpares(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));

    System.out.println("Impressao dos Numeros Pares");
    List<Integer> listaPares = mapParesImpares.get("pares");
    listaPares.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("\n\n");

    System.out.println("Impressao dos Numeros Impares");
    List<Integer> listaImpares = mapParesImpares.get("impares");
    listaImpares.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```